# SQL Server : need a single row data for a table having column with same id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need all the columns for both rows with same id 1 but termed different so that I can distinguish which column belongs to which row.

I have data like below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` 
(
    `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `rev` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `test` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`rev`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `rev`, `content`,`test`) 
VALUES ('1', '1', '11','33'),
       ('1', '2', '22','44');
```

I used the query below :

```
SELECT 
    A.id, A.content as priorcontent, B.content as currcontent
FROM 
    docs A
INNER JOIN 
    docs B ON A.id = B.id
```

but I don't get a result as expected

```
id  priorcontent    currcontent
-------------------------------
 1      11              11
 1      11              22
 1      22              11
 1      22              22
```

What I want is

```
id  priorcontent  currcontent  priortest  currtest
---------------------------------------------------
1      11           22             33        44
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this doesn't seem like SQL Server. Are you using MySQL instead?

Comment: I think it might help if you verbally explain how the data should be handled, meaning what comes from where and why. Now priorcontent May be from content or test column etc. It’s quite unclear.

Comment: i need all the columns for both rows with same id 1 but termed different so that i can distinguish which column belongs to which row

Comment: @user9807332, so which one of these is the winner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want the two separate versions with the same "id", to be displayed in the same row. To get the result you showed above, use:

```
SELECT A.id, A.content as priorcontent
     , B.content as currcontent 
     , A.test priorcontent2
     , B.test currcontent2
FROM docs A
      INNER JOIN docs B ON A.id = B.id and A.rev=1 and B.rev=2
```

Comment: Thank You. This Worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for here but this will work with this specific data/request:

```
 select a.id, a.content priorcontent, b.content currcontent, a.test priorcontent2, b.test currcontent2 
  from docs a join docs b on a.rev+1=b.rev and a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id, 
A.content as priorcontent, B.content as currcontent,
A.test as priortest, B.test as currtest
FROM docs A
inner JOIN docs B ON A.id = B.id and A.rev < B.rev
```

Answer (score 0):

You are matching on ID column.  Seems that there are multiple occurrences of the ID in one or both tables, e.g. if ID 1 appeared in tableA twice and TableB 3 times, you'd see 6 (3 x 2) rows.  Since you are seeing 4 rows, both have 2 copies or one has 4 copies of the same ID.